# Inserting a numeric value to cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cell

My professor has a unique task that prevents us from using any JQuery or basically anything that isn't Javascript or HTML/CSS.

I have to, on a mouse click, update the value within a cell with some numeric value.  I am new to Javascript and basically here is what I am working with.

```
<table id="score">
                <tr>
                    <td> One's </td>
                    <td class="scoring" id="ones" onClick="inputScore()">  </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is click the cell with id=ones and insert a value of 50 with the function inputScore().  What is the best way to approach this using only Javascript? Thanks in advance.

#### Edit: Code ported from comments:

```
<script>
  function inputScore() { 
    var x = 50; 
    document.getElementById("ones") = x; 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: For an assignment question, can you please show what code you have started with? Most of us are reluctant to give complete answers to assignments or exams.  Post your function definition, and where you got stuck.

Comment: ...And for what it's worth, you should thank your professor for prohibiting jQuery while you learn.  Lots of people _never_ bother to learn how JavaScript really works, and get really stuck when the need comes use it as designed.

Comment: `<script>
   function inputScore() {
    var x = 50;
    document.getElementById("ones") = x;
   }
  </script>`  This is more or less what I am trying to do, he didn't go into great detail on how to do this and I cannot find anything concrete online about this type of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly targeted the element with `getElementById()`, but you need to set its `innerHTML` property to modify the cell's contents.

```
function inputScore() { 
  var x = 50; 
  document.getElementById("ones").innerHTML = x; 
}
```

You were very nearly there.  In this case you could also use `.innerText` since you are not adding any additional HTML markup, only the number `50`.

If you want, you might consider modifying this function to accept the new value as a parameter:

```
function inputScore(value) {
  // Set the contents to value
  document.getElementById("ones").innerHTML = parseInt(value, 10);
}
// Called as
inputScore(50)
```

As you learn, it is recommended to use the MDN documentation as your point of reference. [Here is the documentation on `.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a desire to learn this to the best of my ability, are there any publications that are well good for javascript? I like having books :P

Comment: @ZachM. My favorite is JavaScript: The good Parts by Douglas Crockford, but it is not really a beginner book.  It _does_ explain how JS is often _misused_ though, which is really valuable.  I don't have any beginner book recommendations unfortunately.  The MDN docs are really excellent, and avoid w3schools.com.

Comment: ah I had been using w3schools.com thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @ZachM. Generally the info there is pretty out of date, and sometimes encourages bad practices. It is _not affiliated_ with the w3c.